# Overlaps and running multiple node processes

Tags: node.js, multithreading

Background: I'm currently building an application that needs to 'update' users information every 4 hours. It does this by requesting data from an external API (Riot's API)

My question is that with one process I can only update about 76,000 users every 4 hours and thinking about scalability I thought what do I do if/when i reach 500k users, 1M users ect

I've read up that you can run multiple node processes (one for each core of your cpu) at the same time.

So i was wondering if i have say 10 processes working at the same time how do i avoid overlaps of updates for users. (What's to stop all 10 processes updating the same set of users)

Note: I have thought about using some kind of workaround such as giving each process a range of names (process 1 does all names that begin with a-d and so forth) but I feel that this approach feels more like a hack than a solution

Comment: I think you'd want to rethink your update strategy to get to higher scale.  Since most user information won't change at all in a 4 hour period, you need to concentrate on how to only update user's information when there was actually a change.  That will lead to a much, much higher scale than adding processes.  Also, keep in mind if all these processes are all contending for the same database, your DB may be the bottleneck.

Comment: The thing is that if i leave a user for more than 4 hours without checking there data via an external api i could lose out on data. As only the users last 10 games are kept in the api. I have definitely thought of using some kind of system to puts users to sleep when no new activity has been detected in a set period of time, so if a player stops playing completely i won't be scanning them every 4 hours but rather once a day, or once every 2 days ect

Answer (score 0):

One typical solution is to use a work queue. Check [the documentation for bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull) for an example. Note especially the section on cluster:

> Queues are robust and can be run in parallel in several threads or processes without any risk of hazards or queue corruption. Check this simple example using cluster to parallelize jobs accross processes...

If you want to spread out the work load across multiple servers, pay more attention to [the section on using it as message queue](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull#message-queue).

Comment: Thanks a ton will explore these links